# Same rule, different target and dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to remove some duplication from my Makefile. It takes files with lists of hosts and concatenates them into larger groups. For example, this would generate `hosts/west.txt` from the content of `hosts/oregon.txt hosts/washington.txt hosts/idaho.txt` and so on.

```
ALLFILE = hosts/all.txt
WESTFILE = hosts/west.txt
EASTFILE = hosts/east.txt
GENERATEDFILES = $(ALLFILE) $(WESTFILE) $(EASTFILE)

ALLFILES = $(filter-out $(GENERATEDFILES), $(wildcard hosts/*.txt))
WESTFILES = hosts/oregon.txt hosts/washington.txt hosts/idaho.txt
EASTFILES = hosts/new_york.txt hosts/virginia.txt

$(ALLFILE) : $(ALLFILES)
    @echo '# DO NOT EDIT' > $@
    @echo '# Edit individual host/ files instead.' >> $@
    @echo '# Regenerate with `make`.' >> $@
    @echo '' >> $@
    cat $^ >> $@

$(WESTFILE) : $(WESTFILES)
    @echo '# DO NOT EDIT' > $@
    @echo '# Edit individual host/ files instead.' >> $@
    @echo '# Regenerate with `make`.' >> $@
    @echo '' >> $@
    cat $^ >> $@

$(EASTFILE) : $(EASTFILES)
    @echo '# DO NOT EDIT' > $@
    @echo '# Edit individual host/ files instead.' >> $@
    @echo '# Regenerate with `make`.' >> $@
    @echo '' >> $@
    cat $^ >> $@
```

I'd like to remove that redundant code. Either by making all the target/dependency combos share one rule, or by some other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(ALLFILE) : $(ALLFILES)
$(WESTFILE) : $(WESTFILES)
$(EASTFILE) : $(EASTFILES)

$(ALLFILE) $(WESTFILE) $(EASTFILE):
    @echo '# DO NOT EDIT' > $@
    @echo '# Edit individual host/ files instead.' >> $@
    @echo '# Regenerate with `make`.' >> $@
    @echo '' >> $@
    cat $^ >> $@
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! `$(ALLFILE) $(WESTFILE) $(EASTFILE)` can even be replaced with `$(GENERATEDFILES)`.